# RxJava2 Flowable.combineLastest()-like operator(s) to combine when only selected stream emits

Tags: rx-java2

For example I have A,B,C,D flowables emitting independently. For example where this maps to Foo:

```
Flowable<Foo> fooStream = Flowable.combineLatest(A,B,C,D -> Foo::new);
```

And it emits whenever A, B, C or D emits an update. a new Foo is emitted downstream.

Which combination of operators, if any, could I use for merging (A,B,C,D)'s latest result into Foo ONLY some select flowable (lets say A) emits?

Answer (score 0):

There is exactly operator you need: `withLatestFrom`

`A.withLatestFrom(B, C, D, Foo::new)`

It will emit every time A emits, with latest values from B, C and D. 
Keep in mind B, C and D must have value in them. So if for ex. D didn't emit anything at all, stream will get stuck.